# Get value for given index in QML LISTMODEL

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have a QML ListModel like follows:

```
ListModel {
id: myListModel
ListElement {myId: "1", myValue = "12"}
ListElement {myId: "2", myValue = "0"}
...
ListElement {myId: "21", myValue = "123"}
}
```

Then I have some simple QML labels like follows:

```
Label {
id: myLabel1
property int labelInt: 1
text: myListModel.get().myValue; //Here is my problem!
}

Label {
id: myLabel2
property int labelInt: 22
text: myListModel.get().myValue; //Here is my problem!
}
```

My problem is to fill that brackets in myListMode.get().myValue.
In fact I need a condition:
**if myListModel has some myId that equals my current labelInt,
then return me the corresponding myId, otherwise leave empty space:**

I tried with:

```
myListModel.get(myListModel.get(myId = labelInt).myId).myValue;
```

but I am not sure It's the proper way.

Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: Try `ListElement {myId: "1", myValue: "12"}` - `:` instead of `=`. Also, see here for how to search thorough a list model: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991438/how-do-i-find-a-particular-listelement-inside-a-listmodel-in-qml

Comment: Doesn't work :-(

Comment: Will the `myId` that you query, vary often? Will the content of the `ListModel` change often?

Comment: Yes, it's always different!

Comment: During the runtime of the programm: Will data be **appended** and/or **removed** from the `ListModel`?  Will, for one entry in the `ListModel` the values be constant over time, may all change, or is at least `myId` constant?

Comment: They all can change dinamically. That's why I am looking for a generic formula!

Comment: Could you set `myId` with the same value as the index for each `ListElement`? Another option is to use a map to store the pair `ListElement` index and your `myId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you speed is your desire, you should map you entries to the `myId`.

In QML you can do this with a combination of a `Instantitator` and a `JSObject`.

```
property var tracker: ({})

Instantiator {
    model: tm
    delegate: QtObject {
        id: instDummy
        property QtObject modelData: model
        property string __oldID
        property string myID: model.myID

        onMyIDChanged: {
            if (myID && __oldID !== myID) {
                delete tracker[__oldID]
                __oldID = myID
                tracker[__oldID] = instDummy
                console.log('changed', Object.keys(tracker))
            }
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            __oldID = myID
        }
        Component.onDestruction: {
            console.log(__oldID, modelData.myID, delete tracker[__oldID])
            console.log('removed', Object.keys(tracker))
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

The `Instantiator` creates a `QtObject` for each entry in the model. This `QtObject` stores a reference to the model data of the entry. The two properties `myID` and `__oldID` are used to keep the `Map (JSObject) tracker` up to date.

`myID` is bound to the `model.myID` so, whenever this would change it would trigger the signal on `myID`changed. Now I need to change the key in the map from the old value to the new value. Therefore I delete the entry with the key `__oldID`, then I update `__oldID` to the new `myID` and add the object back into the map, with the new key.

I don't want `__oldID` to be bound, therefore I assign it in `Component.onCompleted`.

When the entry is removed, I remove the object and the reference from the `Map` as well, so I keep my map as clean as possible.

When a new entry is added, the `Instantiator` will automatically add a new `QtObject` for this.

---

Now you can query your `myID` in `O(1)` with `tracker[myID]`. The `Instantiator` takes care that all changes will be tracked. It only changes, when there is a change to the model in the specific row.

Note that this method will take a toll on your memory, as it will basically duplicate your model in the hashmap.

To avoid this, you might implement a `ProxyModel` in C++, e.g. based on the `QIdentityProxyModel` to which you add a mapping of the `myID` and the actuall model index. Handle the `dataChanged`-signal to keep that map up-to-date.

PS: I expect that at least the `myID` is unique. Otherwise like this, you might lose some references. Use buckets then, to keep multiple entries in the map for shared `myID`'s

Comment: Thank you @derM, really interesting answer! Could you explain the code a bit more, please? I am new in QML..

Comment: I tried to. For mor information read the documentation, or ask specifically, where your problems still are. If you expect the answer to this question to be in much detail you may also consider creating a new question, referencing this one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through your model to find the element.

Example:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {

    function findElement(myModel, myId) {
        for(var i = 0; i < myModel.count; i++) {
            var element = myModel.get(i);

            if(myId == element.myId) {
                console.log("Found element: ", i);
                return element.myId;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }


    id: window
    visible: true

    TableView {
        y: 70
        width: 500

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "myId"
            title: "myId"
            width: 100
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "myValue"
            title: "myValue"
            width: 100
        }

        model: myListModel

        ListModel {
            id: myListModel
            ListElement
            {
                myId: "1"
                myValue: "12"
            }
            ListElement
            {
                myId: "2"
                myValue: "0"
            }
            ListElement
            {
                myId: "21"
                myValue: "123"
            }
        }
    }

    Label
    {
        id: myLabel1
        property int labelInt: 1
        x: 0
        text: findElement(myListModel, labelInt);
    }

    Label
    {
        id: myLabel2
        property int labelInt: 22
        x: 100
        text: findElement(myListModel, labelInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! However this method slows down the program so much, that I really need to find another solution :-(