# How to create a ListView of different kind of Components and access to them

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create a horizontal ListView with different kinds of components, so I've solved it this way:

```
ListModel {
    id: filtersModel
    ListElement {
        type: "agencies"
    }
    ListElement {
        type: "calendar"
    }
}

ListView {
    id: filtersList
    orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    model: filtersModel
    delegate: chooser
    
    DelegateChooser {
        id: chooser
        role: "type"
        DelegateChoice { 
            roleValue: "agencies"
            delegate: 
            ComboBox
            {
                id: agencies
                ...
            }
        }

        DelegateChoice {
            roleValue: "calendar"
            Button
            {
                id: calendarBtn
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that I want to change some properties of that objects inside of the ListView, but I don't know if it is possible/correct to access to them.

If I use the id's that I've defined for each component, my code throws an error because it can't recognize them.

For example, I need to change the text of the button, but this is not correct:

```
calendarBtn.text = "Date"
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, where do you want to change it from? Before which event do you want to change it? Typically the view is modified using the information from the model.

Comment: @eyllanesc for example, when I press the button, I display a Calendar and I have to set its anchors according to the button. Then, when I select the date on the Calendar, I change the text of the button with the information of the selected date.

Comment: Could you provide a [MRE] of that, we need that code to understand the problem and then point you to a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend changing the way you implemented the Model-View and the way you are imagining it here. Model-View programming is best suited for data of the same type. If you want to have horizontal items in a row consider using [Row](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-row.html).

Now, for your problem [itemAtIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#itemAtIndex-method) may help. I believe QML is smart enough, so you can just do something like this:

```
filtersList.itemAtIndex(#).text = "Date"
```

and how to find the value for `#`? May be something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991438/how-do-i-find-a-particular-listelement-inside-a-listmodel-in-qml).